# How to get customer ip address in joomla payment gateway extension

Tags: php

below code not working in joomla:

code1: not working in joomla this code

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

code 2:  not working in joomla below code

```
function getUserIP() {
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    else if(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip;
```

could you please help me.

Comment: This is nothing to with Joomla. Joomla is based on PHP and if your code works then it should work in Joomla too.

Comment: When you say "does not work" what do you mean?  What is the expected behavior of your code and what is the actual behavior?

Answer (score 0):

### [How to get visitor's IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078574/how-to-get-customer-ip-address-in-joomla-payment-gateway-extension)

#### Use this code:

```
   function checkIPAddress()
   {
      // Get IP Address using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $ipaddress = ($_SERVER('REMOTE_ADDR')) ? $_SERVER('REMOTE_ADDR') : '';

       if ( filter_var ($ipaddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) == false)
       {
          $ipaddress = '';
       }
       return $ipaddress;
   }
```

**Allow HTTP_X_FORWARDED is a bad habit. Use it when you are doing proxy server, load balancing etc**

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUserIP() {
    $ip = null;
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

$user_ip = getUserIP();
echo $user_ip;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, about code is working in php well and this code if i use joomla extension is not working, could you please help me